# HashMap cannot cast other type?

Tags: hashmap

public Human setName(){
        Human a=null;

```
    System  .out.println("change name ");
    System.out.println("enter Security No : ");
    String inputsecNo=sc.next();

    System.out.println("enter name you wish to change : ");
    String name=sc.next();
    Human value=null;
    value= humanList.get(inputSecNo);
    value.setName(name);
```

I don't know why this error occur...
I made a HashMaphumanList 
and want to get value of key(String). 
it says HashMap cannot be cast to Human...
i used iterator to get value of map. but it occur same error.

Comment: the thing I want is to get value which is mapped into key(inputSecNo)

Comment: This one doesn't work at all too. Set<String> keys = humanList.keySet();
  Iterator<String> it=keys.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext()){
   String key=it.next();
   a=humanList.get(key);
   a.setName(name);
   System.out.println("done.");
  }